# Code Contracts and Auto Generated Files

Tags: wpf-controls, code-contracts

When I enabled code contracts on my WPF control project I ran into a problem with an auto generated file which was created at compile time (XamlNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper). Note, the generated file is called GeneratedInternalTypeHelper.g.cs and is not the same as the GeneratedInternalTypeHelper.g.i.cs which there are several obsolete blog posts about.

I'm not exactly sure what its purpose is, but I am assuming it is important for some internal reflection to resolve XAML. The problem is that it does not have code contracts, nor is the code contract system smart enough to recognize it as an auto generated file. This leads to a bunch of errors from the static checker.

I tried searching for a solution to this problem, but it seems like nobody is developing WPF controls and using code contracts. I did come across an interesting attribute, ContractVerificationAttribute, which takes a boolean value to set whether the assembly or class is to be verified. This allows you to decorate a class as not verified. Sadly the GeneratedInternalTypeHelper is regenerated with every compile, so it is not possible to exclude just this one class. The inverse scenario is possible though, decorate the assembly as not verified and then opt in for every class.

To mitigate the obvious hack I wanted to create a test that would at least verify that the exposed classes have code contract verification with a test like the following to ensure that own classes were at least being verified:

```
[Fact]
public void AllAssemblyTypesAreDecoratedWithContractVerificationTrue()
{
    var assembly = typeof(someType).Assembly;
    var exposedTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Namespace) && t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyNamespace") && !t.Name.StartsWith("<>"));

    var areAnyNotContractVerified = exposedTypes.Any(t =>
    {
        var verificationAttribute = t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ContractVerificationAttribute), true).OfType<ContractVerificationAttribute>();
        return verificationAttribute.Any() && verificationAttribute.First().Value;
    });

    Assert.False(areAnyNotContractVerified);
}
```

As you can see it takes all classes in the controls assembly and finds the one from the company namespace which are not also auto generated anonymous types (<>WeirdClassName).

(I also need to exclude Resources and settings, but I hope you get the idea).

I'm not loving the solution since there are ways of avoiding contract verification, but currently it's the best I can come up with. If anyone has a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: Some of the comments on this https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/483730/code-analysis-does-not-exclude-wpf-generated-files suggest going into the Code Analysis tab, unchecking and rechecking the "suppress results from generated code" and trying again. Apparently it's an issue with VS2010 itself, not just CC.

Answer (score 0):

So you can treat this class exactly like you would treat any other "3rd party" class or library. I'm sure certain assumptions would hold with the interaction with this generated class so at the interaction points, decorate your own code with `Contract.Assume(result != null)` or similar.

```
var result = new GennedClass().GetSomeValue();
Contract.Assume(result != null);
```

What this does is translate into an assertion that is checked at run time, but it allows the static analyzer to reason about the rest of the code that you do control.